# Prove that $a_n$ is null sequence for $a_{n}=n$ when $10\ge n$ and $a_{n}=\frac1n$ when $n>10. $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I don't want the proof for this question since I have already done one. But what I want is the explanation for the counterintuitive proof that the book provided me with.Here is it:

[image]

Let me give the details about 36(a) and 36(c).

36(a) Every subsequence of null sequence is null.

36(c)  For some fixed positive integer k, The sequence $a_{n+k}$ is null if $a_{n}$ is null.

Explain me the proof in photo not the definition 36 (a and c).

Thanks for entertainment!

Comment: $36c$ simply means that we can omit or add finite many entries to a sequence without changing the limit. This is intuitively obvious. $36a$ follows from the Cauchy-criterion.

Comment: @Peter I already know it.Just explain me the proof in picture not the definition I provided.

Comment: The method of the proof is to delete some entries to get a sequence that can be identified as a null-sequence. To get a "usual" sequence with start index $1$, the sequence is then shifted. Both operations do not change the limit, hence the original sequence must be a null-sequence.